# Kerberos and google-authenticator (2-factor auth)

Tags: authentication, pam, kerberos

Does anyone know how can I use google-authenticator in combination with kerberos and thus provide to my users 2-factor authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok problem solved (in theory). There actually 2 options: Rolling out your own 2-factor authentication using GSS-API [1] or using the AuthHub and AuthHub-TOTP magnificent plugins [2].

[1] http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-twofactors/

[2] https://fedorahosted.org/AuthHub/wiki/GettingStarted

Comment: maybe you should accept your answer here? Also, any chance you could expand, in case the links break in the future?